# Enabling email verification in laravel 5.2 - InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php

Tags: laravel-5, email-verification

**To enable email verification in laravel 5.2 , I found this error :**

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [**Activate account** <ahref="http:..localhost:8000.user.activation.3223338c9bef4f1ea34e4caff92fff2497c5c94b77e2665bfc975a9684df6e32">click here<.a>] **not found**.
```

**I used**

```
$link = route('user.activate', $token);             
$message = sprintf('**Activate account** <a href="%s">%s</a>', $link, $link);
$this->mailer->send($message , [$message], function (Message $m) use ($user) 
{             
    $m->to($user->email)->subject('Activation mail');
```

**I used this route:**

```
Route::get('user/activation/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@activateUser')->name('user.activate');
```

Comment: Please style your answer properly, it is nearly impossible to read anything from that wall of text!

Comment: I modify , basically i got code form here https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-email-verification-with-activation-code.html#.WR75NBNEnIU

Comment: I want to know to how to send email verification to any email id in laravel 5.2 by online server

Comment: Laravel Mailer expects `$message` to be a path to a Blade template, not a HTML string. Move your HTML into a Blade template and call the appropriate path.

Comment: plz write that blade template